# How can I connect two seams on a mesh? They come apart while posing but not while modeling

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, armature, workflow

I am learning how to rig properly using this simple molecule character.  I joined all the spheres and created seams by using ctrl-F and self-intersect.  I then deleted the internal faces.  The molecule now comes apart when I am testing the armature.

[image]

However, when I am modeling, there is no break in the seam; it is connected:

[image]

What can i do to make the seams remain connected while i am posing the character?

Here is the .Blend file:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file?

Comment: @ShadyPuck Yes, I will.  Just a moment.

Comment: @ShadyPuck This .8 MB file has been sitting there for a while and has not yet begun to process.  Am i doing something wrong?  Is there some way to make the file smaller for uploading purposes?

Comment: Never mind, I skipped a step.  Here comes the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Idle Chit-chat

Ok, I switched to answer to give a more detailed, well, answer! It appears that your mesh is not actually one piece, despite appearances.

### Problem

I am not familiar with the self-intersect tool you described (or *Ctrl + F* if those are one and the same), but the spheres are separate. I proved this by selecting a single verticy of one of the spheres and keying *L*. If the mesh were a whole, like rigging requires, everything would select. Everything, obviously, did not.

### Solution

Luckily, there is a simple solution! Select the entire mesh with *A*, key *W*, and select *Remove Doubles*:

[image]

This will join all the seemingly joined edge loops. Now you can continue on and rig!

Comment: Thank you, this indeed connected the shapes!  I still would like to know *why* the shapes behave as one mesh while modeling, then separate during pose mode.  Also, why does the model look neat and tidy in edit mode, but has horrible seams in object mode?  I guess I'll have to post this as a separate question.

Comment: @WishyQ Glad to help. To answer your other question, unlike in real life, in Blender two or more objects with volume can occupy the same point(s) in space. Therefore, it is always ACTING as separate objects, as proved by my Key L test. It simply doesn't appear this way.